# What's the "proper" way to get value of LiveData in ViewModel, other than using Transformations?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

what is the "proper" (idiomatic) way to get the value of LiveData in ViewModel? I am aware of Transformations, but it just won't do it, as that particular LiveData has no observers... I've been using this:

```
    // triggered by user interaction, fetch value of Live Data
    mLiveData.observeForever(new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> values) {
                mLiveData.removeObserver(this);
                // process values...
            }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: huh? The observer should receive new values. If you need to "process values", then use `Transformations.map`.

Comment: However, mLiveData is not observed in my Fragment, hence I can't use Transformations...

Comment: I'd think if you observe the mapped version then it should internally also start observing the original source. Is it not so?

Comment: here's how this can be achieved, using `Flow`:
`mLiveData.asFlow().onEach { // do stuff }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
`